# In a rails view, how can I send output to view besides <%= %>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## Short version:

It seems weird to me to have rails code like, say,

```
<% if @list.empty
  %><%= val %><%
end %>
```

Is there some way to do something like this?

```
<% if @list.empty
  some_display_function_i_wish_existed val
end %>
```

## Long version:

I have a model, tweet.rb, that overrides to_s. The to_s works fine.

I have a view that needs to output to_s for each tweet in @meme.tweets .

I've observed the following:

```
<% @meme.tweets.each do |tweet|
   tweet 
end %>
```

Result: no output

```
<% @meme.tweets.each do |tweet|
  puts tweet # or tweet.to_s does the same thing
end %>
```

...Result: no output

```
<%= @meme.tweets.each do |tweet|
   tweet 
end %>
```

...Result: output is entire inspection of each tweet, not to_s

```
<%= @meme.tweets.each do |tweet|
  puts tweet # or tweet.to_s does the same thing
end %>
```

...Result: output is entire inspection of each tweet, not to_s

```
<% @meme.tweets.each do |tweet| %>
   <%= tweet %>
<% end %>
```

...Result: works as intended (outputs result of to_s for each tweet). So does:

```
<%= @meme.tweets.collect do |tweet|
   tweet.to_s
end %>
```

...Result: works as intended.

I come from a PHP background, and don't really understand the rules here.

I know I *can* do it the way I did in the last example.

But could someone explain why none of the other examples work as I intend?

It seems to me that the rules APPEAR to be:

1) <%= something %> will take that thing, call to_s on it, which will default to inspect if not overridden.

2) <% something %> will execute something

Is there a way to use 2) <% %> to send output to the view?

Or is it against the rules to have <% %> tags that span multiple lines of ruby code at all?

Comment: Your 2nd to last example is the correct way.  Use the `=` variation to output, and the one lacking equals for control structures and non-outputting code.  You can span multiple lines if you want, but the non-outputting tag shouldn't/won't output anything.  And unlike php, where `echo`ing in the template is standard practice, it is not idiomatic with ruby and `puts`.

Comment: Also, the second-to-last example, in addition to being correct, also makes it easy to extract the rendering to a partial or helper. Which in turn makes it easier to use the automagic "render this collection" or "render this instance" partial stuff work.

Comment: `<% %>` and `<%= %>` may wrap an expression which can span multiple lines.  Note that an expression may be composed of many sub-expressions. In the case of `<%= %>` the return value of the encapsulated expression is added to the view. E.g. `<%= x = 1; x + 2 %>` will concat "3" to the view output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= code %>` will print to the the output the result of the inner code. `<% %>` won't print anything, it just evaluates the inner code.
That's why the first example doesn't work. On the second example you expect the `puts` to print the tweets, but `puts` doesn't print on the same buffer... (you'll see the tweets printed on the rails console instead).

On 3rd and 4th example you are printing the collection as an object (`@meme.tweets.each` returns an `Enumerable` and ERb call `#to_s` on that) and not the code inside the block.

The 5th form is correct. That's what you'll normally do.
The 6th form is in some way correct too. There you are iterating a collection, calling `#to_s` on each element and then `collect`ing them on a new array, that gets printed to the output (but you are printing an array of strings, not just one big string).

you can get a similar result with `#join`. *(It returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string)*

```
<%= @meme.tweets.join %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<% %>` are used when you do **not** want the Ruby code you're executing to output anything. The `<%= %>` tags are used when you want to output something. This is why your example using `<%= %>` and `tweet.to_s` works as intended.

If you don't specify which attribute you want to output, then yes, `puts` will display the whole object. If for example, you had a `message` attribute on your `tweet` object, writing `tweet.message` (inside of a `<%= %>`, of course) would output just the message attribute of that tweet.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is the [`concat` function](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat), eg:

```
Hi, my name is <% concat("Shelvacu") %>.
```

which is the same as

```
Hi, my name is <%= "Shelvacu" %>.
```

Which both output `Hi, my name is Shelvacu.`

---

Think of it like this: An erb template is parsed, transformed into valid ruby code, and then that ruby code is run*. Everything that is *not* inside `<% ... %>` is converted to `concat("...")`, `<% statement %>` is converted to `statement`, and `<%= statement %>` is converted to `concat(statement.to_s)`.

So when ERB sees

```
1 + 2 = <%= 1 + 2 %>

<% puts "hello" %>

<% @meme.tweets.each do |tweet| %>
   <%= tweet %>
<% end %>
```

that code is then translated to*

```rb
concat("1 + 2 = ")
concat((1 + 2).to_s)
concat("\n\n")
puts "hello"
concat("\n\n")
@meme.tweets.each do |tweet|
  concat(tweet.to_s)
end
```

* This is an oversimplification, ERB does much more so that errors point the right line, statements don't merge with eachother in unexpected ways, and I didn't even mention `<%- ... %>`. However, this should be a decent mental model for understanding whats happening when you write code in ERB.